# Does Fabric.js Support SMIL Animations?

Tags: svg, fabricjs, smil

I can't find any reference to them in the documentation, but it seems like the library has the capabilities to support SMIL

Comment: Not at the moment, no. We do support animations but we don't parse them from SVG.